# How to scroll horizontally when there are many columns (or a very long row)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollview, multiple-columns

I am trying to add many headers (as a row) so that I can scroll horizontally to the right.

How do I do that.

Live Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/szve8s2w/1/

HTML CODE:

```
<div id="background">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <h3>Column1</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <h3>Column2</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <h3>column3</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <h3>column4</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <h3>column5</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <h3>column6</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <h3>column7</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <h3>Column8</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <h3>Column9</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <h3>column10</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS CODE

```
#background
{ 
    position: relative;
    background-color:#9B59B6;
    width:100%;
    height: 100%;

}
```

Instead on being headers, each all the column went down. I want all of the column(n) be headers, and I can scroll horizontally to see the last column(n).

And the background does not cover all the page, It seems to only cover the column, the rest of the background is white.

I know I will have to do it with javascript, but I don't really have experience in javascript.

Please help, I am new to html and css. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No JS needed, pretty simple when you know how.

```
#background { 
    position: relative;
    background-color:#9B59B6;
    width:100%;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.col-sm-2 { display: inline-block; }
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: No problem @JasonChristopher Glad it helped

Answer (score 1):

Hope this will help

```
#background{ 
    position: relative;
    background-color:#9B59B6;
    width:100%;
    height: 200px;
 }
.row{
width:100%;
overflow-x:scroll;
height: 200px;
}
.col-sm-2{
width:auto;
display:table-cell;
}
h3{
width:200px;
}
```

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/szve8s2w/5/)

Comment: Why would you use display: table-cell; ?